# AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'crop'

Tags: python, compiler-errors, python-imaging-library, crop

I'm getting this error :
''
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'crop'
''
I am trying to open the screenshot I took in the program, and crop it to a desired height and width.
I'm a novice to Python. Plz. help.

Here's the code :

```
x = 3
y = 37
ss = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, 1950, 1200))
blurImage = ss.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius =15))
filter=ImageEnhance.Brightness(blurImage)
brightImage=filter.enhance(0.7)
ss = ImageTk.PhotoImage(brightImage)
root.state('zoomed')
image1 = tk.Label(root, image=ss)
image1.image = ss
image1.place(x=0, y=0)
left = 155
top = 65
right = 360
bottom = 270
brightImage=filter.enhance(0.7)
ss= ImageTk.PhotoImage(brightImage)
im1 = ss.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
image2 = Label(root, image=im1)
image2.image=im1
image2.place(x=35, y=35)
```

Comment: Judging from the function names, you appear to be using PIL (or Pillow).  ImageTk PhotoImage does not have a crop method.  Creating a TkImage should generally be the last step: you must do the crop when the image is in the form of a regular PIL Image object (for example, your objects "blurImage" or "brightImage").

Comment: I tried Your Suggestion, and shifted my crop method and label to just after the declaration of "brightImage" but now it says : _tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=205x205 at 0x2290BDD8430>" doesn't exist

Comment: Please post your updated program listing, and indicate what line the error occurs in.

Comment: '
x = 3
y = 37
ss = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, 1950, 1200))
blurImage = ss.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius =15))
left = 155
top = 65
right = 360
bottom = 270
im1 = blurImage.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
image2 = Label(root, image=im1)
image2.image=im1
filter=ImageEnhance.Brightness(blurImage)
brightImage=filter.enhance(0.7)
ss = ImageTk.PhotoImage(brightImage)
root.state('zoomed')
image1 = tk.Label(root, image=ss)
image1.image = ss
image1.place(x=0, y=0)


brightImage=filter.enhance(0.7)
ss= ImageTk.PhotoImage(brightImage)
'

Comment: and the error is : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\advai\PycharmProjects\firstprog\trial.py", line 23, in <module>
    image2 = Label(root, image=im1)
  File "C:\PYTHON 39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3148, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\PYTHON 39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=205x205 at 0x233FF840FD0>" doesn't exist

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: TkInter cannot display PIL.Image objects.  It can only display TkImage.PhotoImage objects.  So when you try to execute the line: `image2 = Label(root, image=im1)` you get an error, because at that point im1 is a PIL.Image (not a TkImage.PhotoImage).  You have to keep track of this stuff yourself, so you know what type each variable is.  The PIL library has a huge number of functions you can use on PIL.Image objects, but you can't display them with TkInter.  Before you display an image you must convert it to a format the Tk can handle.  You can do almost nothing with that converted image.

Comment: For future reference, don't post code or tracebacks into comments on this site.  The formatting will be lost, and Python requires strict formatting.  Your program was simple enough that I could decipher your comment, but it would be hopeless if it was more complicated.

Comment: Okay...Thank you so much for helping me. But is there an alternative to PIL if want to crop an image?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about just the same, as to where I should post my code and not lose all the formatting, I'll keep that in mind...

Comment: PIL works just fine for this and is reasonably fast.  The problem is that TkInter requires a non-standard format, and doesn't have simple built-in support for .jpg, .png or other modern file formats.  But again, PIL's conversion function is fast and works well.  So the combination PIL+TkInter is a good choice, as long as you are careful with your variable types.